# How to await a future in a List.map() function and return a List of strings

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using firebase storage to retrieve is list of download links in a directory. Here is my attempt

```
Future<List<String>> getAllDownloadUrlByDirectory(String item_id) async {
    List<String> links = List.empty(growable: true);

    Reference reference = storage.ref().child('item').child(item_id);
    ListResult results = await reference.listAll();

    return results.items.map((e) async {
      return e.getDownloadURL();
    }).toList());
  }
```

The `results` returns an object with a list that contains the downloadUrl, I am trying to use await/async to get the download link and apply `toList()` and return, but I got a compilation error:

`A value of type 'List<Future<String>>' can't be returned from the method 'getAllDownloadUrlByDirectory' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<String>>'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)`

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to wait for an iterable of futures to complete:

```dart
Future<List<String>> getAllDownloadUrlByDirectory(String item_id) async {
    List<String> links = List.empty(growable: true);

    Reference reference = storage.ref().child('item').child(item_id);
    ListResult results = await reference.listAll();

    final futures = results.items.map((e) {
      return e.getDownloadURL();
    });

    return Future.wait(futures);
  }
```

You should also remove the unnecessary `async` statement in your `map` call.